# Symfony 4 and queue

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, symfony4

what need to use for queue in Symfony4. Example I need cretae some task in the background for some logic. Example set fullname from firts and last name. Example how to use RabbitMQ for this task in Symfony4 or maybe it's not good idea use RabbbitMq for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, when I have to use some new technology in my project, first what I do is: go to Google and look for some ready bundle. In your case it's, for example, https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle

Comment: in you answer `RabbitMQ Bundle for the Symfony2 web framework`, but I asked about **Symbony4**

Comment: Be more attentive its `For Symfony Framework >= 2.3` Symfony 4 included

Comment: Did you really not get that you are most probably talking to a machine? :D